# ASP.Net MVC 4 - more than one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: Process]

I have an MVC 4 application that should do the following:

1- Asks user to enter their Email address (Action 1 -> View 1)

2- Shows acknowledgement of receiving request (Action 2 -> View 2) - **User should be able to close web page here**.

3- Starts long process on server (Action 3) and when finished, notifies user by Email.

How can I achieve this? I will need to create a new thread on Action 2, am I correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a perfect candidate for a CQRS style system to me.

Comment: Sounds correct. Have You Tried It?

Comment: each request in asp.net is handled by a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using task and await included in .net 4.5. Async method example shown:

```
public async Task<List<Gizmo>> GetGizmosAsync()
{
    var uri = Util.getServiceUri("Gizmos");
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Gizmo>>());
    }
}
```

Complete article can be found here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 2):

I would put a message from Action 2 into a message queue of some sort. I'd then have a background process (ideally on a different server) process the message and send the email. That way your web server is freed up to focus on serving web pages and web services and not servicing long running tasks.